# Regex extracts groups of chars that precedes certain

Tags: python, regex

So I have this challenge which if I can choose what to do I would just use split. But the challenge is to come up with a regular expression and I've been scratching my head in addition to googling for examples and trying everything but haven't solve this yet.

```
s = 'Do you like Blah? No I dont like Blah at all, but some times you just get Blah'
```

What would be the expression to extract from the string **s** groups of text like below:

```
'Do you like '
'? No I dont like '
' at all, but some times you just get '
```

Appreciate anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/2JIdbT/1

Check lookaheads and lookbehinds in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

The regular expression
`(?:^|(?<=Blah))(.*?)(?=Blah)`

Will match as few characters as possible on ranges that starts after a "Blah" or at the beginning of the string (denoted by `^`).

Some variations:

`(?:^|(?<=Blah))(.*?)(?:$|(?=Blah))` can also get a match at the end of the input.

`(?:^|(?<=Blah))(.+?)(?:$|(?=Blah))` exclude empty matches

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Bob! And especially thank you for the link to the docs. I'm reading it and trying to translate it to plain English for myself. Hopefully I'll get it soon.